# How to build recursive join with condition using CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, jpa, join, criteria

In my application, I have the following data structure with parent - child relation to other objects of the same class, which looks like following:

```java
@Entity
public class CoreData {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_CORE_ID")
    private CoreData parentCoreData;
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentCoreData", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<CoreData > childCoreData;
    ...
    private String someStringValue;
    private String coreType;
}
```

I would like to build a query using Criteria builder to fetch all CoreData objects of given coreType which meet one of the following conditions:

- `coreData.coreType == searchedCoreType`

**AND (**

- `someStringValue == searchedCoreStringValue`

OR

- coreData's top parent meets condition `someStringValue == searchedCoreStringValue`

**)**

Additionally, I know that there are no cycles of any depth in child-parent relation.

I don't know where to start with building the query. Since I'm looking for lowest children which meet criteria, it would suggest I have to do the following logic with criteria builder:

```java
checkParentCore(core, conditionString) {
    if(core.parentCore == null) {
         if(core.someStringValue == conditionString) {
             return true;
         } else {
             return false;
         }
     } else {
          return checkParentCore(core.parentCore, conditionString)
     }
}
```

However, I have no idea how to do so since it would require some kind of recursive conditional join on the pre-filtered list. Also, this seems very inefficient performance-wise.

Is there a better solution to this problem?

If not then how can I build a recursive conditional join with CriteriaBuilder?

Comment: The answer is you cannot. You will need a native query using whatever recursive construct your RDBMS supports (e.g. `CONNECT BY` or  recursive `WITH <TABLE> AS <SELECT>`)